# Shiny for python - adding an icon to the input_action_button

Tags: python, py-shiny

With R Shiny, adding an icon to an `actionButton` uses `icon()` function.

```
    actionButton(
       ...
      , icon = shiny::icon(icon_name)
    )
```

How can this be achieved with [shiny.ui.input_action_button](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/api/reference/shiny.ui.input_action_button.html?highlight=button#)?

```
    ui.input_action_button(
        ...
        icon = ?
    )
```

Whatever I try in (?) seems to make it into a label instead of an icon.

Answer (score 2):

Only example I found used emoji directly like this

```
ui.input_action_button("go", "Go!", icon="")
```

Not sure you can use icon like R shiny.

Comment: How about a font awesome icon?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answers, one solution I found is using the "faicons" library which include svg icons.

```
from faicons import icon_svg

ui.input_action_button(
        "go" , "Apply" ,  
        icon   = icon_svg("play"), 
        class_ = "btn-primary"
    )
```

A list of all free/pro icons that can be used instead of "play" can be found on Fontawesome website ( https://fontawesome.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

For the functions that accepts icon parameter, you can use an ui.img if you have an image like so:

```
icon=ui.img(src='image.png',
            height='18px',
            style='margin-bottom:2px'
            )
```

but you have to first make sure your www_dir is created which contains the image with the correct Path location and your App() function should have static_assets=www_dir